# Merge tags [alphametic] and [verbal arithmetic]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[alphametic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphametic) and [verbal-arithmetic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbal-arithmetic) refer to the exact same thing, but they are currently not synonymized. Could a mod merge or synonymize them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[verbal-arithmentic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbal-arithmentic) now maps to [alphametic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphametic). Going with the more popular tag as the primary one.